# Does JavaScript and jQuery mean the same thing?

Tags: discussion, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>
> - [Is it okay to post answers using libraries/frameworks/extensions not already mentioned?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40897/is-it-okay-to-post-answers-using-libraries-frameworks-extensions-not-already-ment)
> - [When is “use jQuery” not a valid answer to a JavaScript question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question)

Why do 90% of people reply to question tagged [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) (and not [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)) with a jQuery based answer?

Best answer so far :

> a tag of jQuery implies that a
> JavaScript solution would be
> acceptable, but a tag of JavaScript
> does not, in any way, imply that a
> jQuery solution would be acceptable or
> useful.

Comment: Although migrated from SO for its topic, this was questioned, high viewed, and power answered in a matter of minutes just like a high rep question on SO itself.

Comment: Yeah that's funny XD, I'm new to SO but I love it.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that if you get a JQuery answer to your question, but you need a non-JQuery answer because you can't or don't want to use JQuery for whatever reason, you can usually kind of "translate" it into "vanilla" (non-JQuery) JavaScript by reading the docs, and if necessary, the source, for the JQuery functions that are used.

Comment: Because they don't know native JavaScript and know only how to jQuery everything.

Comment: You should totally drop what you're doing and use Meta!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason I personally, albeit only on occasion, answer JavaScript-tagged questions with a jQuery solution is a simple mistake, every now and then I see a question that would be easy (-ish) to solve with jQuery and, for some reason, don't notice that the question didn't feature the jQuery tag.

It is, on this type of occasion, important to remember [Hanlon's razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon's_razor):

> Never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity.

To answer the implied question in your question's title, which I choose to interpret as 'are JavaScript and jQuery tag-synonyms for each other?' the answer is 'no,' a tag of jQuery implies that a JavaScript solution would be acceptable, but a tag of JavaScript does not, in any way, imply that a jQuery solution would be acceptable or useful.

Comment: +1 I've done that a few times as well.

Comment: Love this answer

Comment: And on the last paragraph you added, very well put. I'd give another + just for that if I could.

Comment: @patrick, I think everyone active in javascript and jquery has done it at least a couple of times =) and thanks!

Comment: @sitifensys: ... *awwww*, shucks... =D

Comment: I don't have enough rep to add a point. But this is exactly the kind of answers I looked for.

Comment: @sitifensys: you *should* [be able to vote up, with >15 rep](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up). Not that you should feel obliged to do so, that was just a pointer at the priveleges to show when you can get to do things.

Comment: This is my +1 for you David XD

Comment: @sitifensys: thank you, kindly! :)

Comment: @david you do deserve it :).

Comment: +1 Oh God, I've done this so many times. And then felt a prize chump immediately afterwards.

Answer (score 9):

Because jQuery makes it [much easier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380521/why-do-people-use-jquery-for-basic-operations/5380554#5380554) to write Javascript.

Answerers generally do not have much time and would prefer to write a single line that uses jQuery and will work in all browsers than to write 10 lines that don't use jQuery and won't work in IE.

The bigger issue is **askers** who ask questions about their "jQuery code" which is actually a simple (but wrong) piece of pure Javascript.

Comment: My question is for askers who ask javascript related things, not jquery. :)

Comment: If you don't want jQuery answers, say so (or use a tag for a different library)

Comment: That's the point of my question. Why people answer javascript **only** tagged question with jquery-ish answers.

Comment: @sti: Because we don't have time to write non-jQuery answers.

Comment: +1 for mentioning JS not working in IE.

Answer (score 5):

They are very different things.

- Javascript is a programming language
- JQuery is a javascript library which has a very high adoption rate amongst web developers using javascript

Comment: I do know what jquery is :), I just asked why people in stack overflow tend to answer javascript only tagged question with jquery shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple: Because jQuery is the answer for a lot of Javascript questions ;-)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a framework written in javascript.

Comment: -1, this answers the title (which is a joke) and not the actual question

Answer (score 1):

Because jQuery is a wildly popular Javascript library which hides lots of JS boilerplate and has tons of plugins for pretty much anything.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there are a lot of people who simply don't know how to work outside of jQuery. That's fine, but I think jQuery does sometimes get over-recommended.

I think that if you ask JavaScript questions, and would prefer non-library answers, you should probably specify that in your question <s>or use the `no-jquery` tag</s>.

---

**EDIT:** The suggestion to use a *not* tag wasn't right. Tags are meant to positively categorize, not negatively.

Comment: Don't use that tag, please. If you you absolutely don't want a jquery answer to a question, say so in the question - it's part of the question's requirements, not a categorization. If you want to *find* JavaScript questions that aren't about jQuery, use the `-[jquery]` search term.

Comment: @Shog9: You're right. `no-jquery` isn't a proper category. I hereby recant. :o) Although I must say that a no jQuery requirement in the question is sometimes insufficient, though it does give good grounds to vote an answer down. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

No. JQuery is built upon JavaScript.

Comment: -1, this answers the title (which is a joke) and not the actual question

Comment: Please restore this. It was part of the migration.